# How is „let’s take a stroll“ said in Das Boot?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Im Film *Das Boot* sagt der Kaleun (2:27:20) in etwa eines der Folgenden (schwer zu hören):

> Mal bisschen die Beine vertreten.
>   Ein bisschen die Beine vertreten.

und die Übersetzung sagte:

> We’re taking a stroll.

Was sagten sie eigentlich?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a movie, not about the German language. We might be able to help if you could show us the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

"Ein bisschen die Beine vertreten." means "Taking a short walk just for the sake of moving around." It's a weird phrase.

I don't know the exact phrase the guy uses, but it could be "Mal'n (Mal ein) Bisschen ..." which is kinda hard to translate literally. The word "mal" (short for "einmal", literally "one time") is thrown in similar to "just" in English, so an idiomatic translation would be "I'll just walk around a bit."

Answer (score 0):

> Mal bisschen die Beine vertreten.

OR

> Ein bisschen die Beine vertreten.

Translated to:

> We’re taking a stroll.

Going back from translation to original it looks like an answer to a question.

So the question was. What are you (guys) doing?
The answer:
We are taking a stroll.

The same in German.

> Was treibt ihr Kerle? OR Was habt Ihr vor?

-

> (Wir gehen uns) mal ein bisschen die Beine vertreten.

The part in brackets is implicit since the question was directed towards them, a group. And the leader of the group or a member answered on behalf of the group. So that would work.

> Mal 'n bisschen die Beine Vertreten.

Would be German too. But dropping the "'n" or the "ein" destroys the German grammar. It would only make sense if the person speaking German was a native English speaker.